# django changes in tests.py don't reflect in models.py

Tags: django, unit-testing

I have a recurring problem when testing my app. whenever I change or create() any object from within tests.py, these changes can't be found in models.py - and that happens **in same test**.

pseudocode:

```
tests.py:
def test_something(self):
    ...
    Norm.objects.create(...)
    self.player_a.print_all_norms()
    ...


models.py:
def print_all_norms():
    a =  Norm.objects.all()
    print a 
    # prints [], the Norm object created in tests.py wasn't found
    return
```

EDIT: 
Clarification - I can't find the object within the test that created it.
A Norm object is created inside test_something(), which calls a function inside models.py.
When the function tries to find the previously created object using Norm.objects.all(), it fails, the test resumes, and then test fails as well.

Comment: I guess you should try to .save() the object

Comment: the create() method has built in saving. as decribed in a couple places on the [making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/) doc page (none with permalink...)

Answer (score 1):

Testing uses temporary database as documented in the [test database docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#the-test-database), so after the test is complete, you won't be able to find those objects through the model manager.

Is it not finding the object within the test or when you try to find it after executing the test?

If it's not finding it in the test, try making sure you have the proper permissions (as mentioned in test db docs)

If you want to load predetermined values into the database on some sort of consistent basis, outside of testing, you may want to at using [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-data-with-fixtures)

Comment: I edited my question. It's not finding the object within the test. I only need that object for that specific test, creating it as part of the TestCase.setUp or loading it from a fixture will lead to failure on other tests. I read the documentation and believe that I have the proper permissions.